# Why do my internet browsers stop working?

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, google-chrome, firefox, web-browser

I have a 13″ mid 2009 MacBook Pro.

For a long time now my browsers just decide to stop working. The 1st occasion Safari kept crashing every 10 minutes so I downloaded Firefox but after a while the same thing kept happening.

I thought it was something to do with Flash so I downloaded a newer version of Flash but that didn't solve anything. I then downloaded Chrome which was fine for a while but now from time to time any browser I use just stops working. I find myself either having to switch my wifi off and on and restart which ever browser I'm using or if that doesn't work, when Safari stops working I switch to Chrome and vice versa.

Comment: Do you get any error / warning?

Comment: Insufficient information to even guess the answer. It could be a number of things.

Comment: When any of your browsers go down, is the Internet still up?

Comment: I think there might be 2 separate issues because if I'm using safari and it crashes an error message appears saying safari quit unexpectedly. If I'm using either safari or another browser and the internet just stops working no error message appears even though I am still connected to the internet. It happened just yesterday, my flatmate and I were both connected to wifi all of a sudden mine stoped working and hers was perfectly fine, mine only started working again when I used a different broswer

Comment: Please add to your original question that you are connected through Wi-Fi since this isn't just a detail and you might discover that this is the core of your problem.

Comment: There is a confusion in your last comment: "the internet just stops working… still connected to the internet". Please clarify and put the useful information inside your question.

Comment: Do you encounter these web browsers misbehavior on a specific web server?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I don't get any error messages or anything. Pages that automatically update just never finish (hamster wheel of death) and if I try to open something new, it won't open. The internet isn't the problem because my husband and daughter don't have the same issues and we're all on at the same time. Turning my wifi off and back on immediately fixes the problem.

Comment: Do you use any Safari Extension? Please provide a screenshot from /Library/Internet Plug-Ins folder. Also try to flush your Cache & Cookiies in Safari Preferences > Privacy > Manage Website Data... Remove all

Answer (score 1):

The first step in narrowing this down is to look at the crash log and the event log in `Console.app` (under `/Applications/Utilities`) to look for relevant error messages.

Usually it is a dns related error, but if that doesn't work, then run the network diagnostics to make sure it isn't just a web browser issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but I found that the cause of it is the apple mail app.
Once I quit apple mail the browsers start working again with no issue, then I relaunch apple mail and all is good for about an hour then it starts again.
Not sure why apple mail is doing this.